# TypeORM migration gives Maximum call stack size exceeded error with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

When I run a migration, I get the following error. I initially had this in one project - now I've created a new blank project and still get the error. Here is the ormconfig.ts:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

const env = {
  "DB_HOST":"localhost",
  "DB_PORT":5432,
  "DB_USERNAME":"postgres",
  "DB_PASSWORD":"postgres",
  "DB_DATABASE":"task-management",
}

export const connectionSource = new DataSource({
  migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
  type: 'postgres',
  host: env.DB_HOST,
  port: env.DB_PORT,
  username: env.DB_USERNAME,
  password: env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: env.DB_DATABASE,
  logging: false,
  synchronize: false,
  name: 'default',
  migrations: ['migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}'],
});
```

I run the migration with: typeorm-ts-node-esm migration:run -d migrations/ormconfig.ts

which gives the following error:

```
 Error during migration run:
    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
        at /Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:29:43
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at loadFileClasses (/Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:29:35)
        at /Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:27:42
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at loadFileClasses (/Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:27:22)
        at /Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:30:17
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at loadFileClasses (/Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:29:35)
        at /Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/nestjs-task-management/node_modules/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:30:17
```

I assume there is some circular dependency causing an infinite loop in DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts, so I put a console.log(JSON.stringify(exported)) on line 26 of DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts, and I now get:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'DataSource'
    |     property 'driver' -> object with constructor 'PostgresDriver'
    --- property 'connection' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at loadFileClasses (/Users/christianayscue/Desktop/nestjsClass/typeormTest/src/util/DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.ts:29:25)
```

It seems DirectoryExportedClassLoader.js is guaranteed to get a Maximum call stack size exceeded error if there are circular dependencies, because it is self-recursive whenever it encounters an object property.

A little help please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing this entry from the DataSource config object fixed the issue.

```
migrations: []
```

This was one of those ones that just took a lot of trial and error to solve...

Comment: I think its important to note that your dbconfig file cannot be in the same directory as your migrations - otherwise you'll have this recursive call.

Comment: If we leave this migrations array empty, when we try to run a migration with the typeorm cli it will not run any migration file

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error, I tried to generate a migration file with TypeORM CLI using `npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs  migration:generate src/migrations/ProductionMigration --dataSource src/dataSource.ts` command but it was throwing Maximum Call Stack exceeded. This happened because in my `dataSource.ts` file inside the `migrations` field I was pointing to `["migrations/*{.ts,.js}"]` folder where I had another typescript file not related to migrations so TypeORM tried to use this file and crashed.

Our migrations field in `dataSource.ts` will only accept files exporting a class that implements the `MigrationInterface` like so:

```
export class MyMigrationClass_SomeId implements MigrationInterface {
 public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
 }

 public async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
 }
}
```

In this question my `dataSource.ts` is equivalent to `ormconfig.ts`, if we leave the migrations array empty when we try to execute the run migrations command
(`npx typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:run -- -d src/dataSource.ts`)
it won't run any migration